# gspread and oauth2client usage

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, gspread, oauth2client

I was trying to use oauth2client and gspread to operate on googlesheet but the problem i have is that when using oauth2client, it requires a field of scope. I have no idea what the scope is. The following is the code of the use of oauth2client.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('gspread-april-2cd … ba4.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("Where is the money Lebowski?").sheet1
```

Comment: Are you unable to open a spreadsheet? Or are you just wondering what the scope is?

Comment: @Burnash I figured out the scope but I then used open_with_url and directly copied the url of my spreadsheet and it shows me 'no spreadsheet found' when I tried my code. The spreadsheet I created was from the same account I created the Google project(or API I forgot what It was called)

Comment: Did you share the spreadsheet with `client_email` in gspread-april-2cd...ba4.json

Comment: That gspread-xxxx.json file is the one downloaded when I created the project right? And the client_email should be the Google account I created the project?

Comment: The best way is to follow the steps in http://gspread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2.html

Comment: Yes,  gspread-xxxx.json is the file you downloaded when you created credentials. `client_email` is a parameter *in this file*, and not the google account.

Comment: That is awesome! Finally works! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth scopes express the permissions you request users to authorize for your app.

The one you used is the only available scope to authorize your request when using [Google Sheets API v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/authorize#authorize_requests_with_oauth_20).

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds
```

While if you used the [Google Sheets API v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing), you can now use either of these two scopes:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly
```

that allows read-only access to the user's sheets and their properties and

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

that allows read/write access to the user's sheets and their properties.